# Modify data From json (php webservice) to mysql by iOS app

Tags: mysql, ios, json

Hello i actually develop a Ios application
This application use a PHP webservice to get data (convert in JSON) from mysql.
Actually it work pretty fine.

But the problem is :
If i want to update, delete, an information.

E.g :

```
@interface Base : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mail;      
...
```

this class is Fill  (after an http request, get JSON) ...

problem :

```
self.mail = @"newmail@mail.com";
```

how can i update this data to my MySQL Databases  ?

- Create another WebService and send data by url ?

  ```
  http://mywebsite/service/baseClassUpdate.php?id=XX&mail=XXXX
  ```
- if yes : is it "Safe" ? cause if someone find this url ...

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to use PHP to do regular REST style web services. Is that right?

Comment: looks like, actually i succes to read a ressource from PHP, but dunno how to modify .. i just need a hint, cause imma lost at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not safe to just send the mail update by a plain request.
First of all those actions should be followed by a password verification and second you should add a md5 hash signature verification to the end and verify that signature on the server...

Also you should send the password in a one way hashed format (md5 or SHA1) and verify the hashed value with what you have in your web server database...

Edit
**To reply to your question to this answer**

Here is what I would do:
I would do this:

```
website/script.php?id=XX&mail=XXXX&password=MD5Pass&signature=MD5signature=MD5Signature
```

the md5signature should be the md5 hash value of all parameters (id) (mail) (password) and a secret password, like ***mySecr3tPass***
So if id=12, mail = mymail@mail.com and pass=AERF124F, the signature would be the MD5 hash of 12mymail@mail.comAERF124FmySecr3tPass, which would be 0b9492395c9c1a73a6622cab5a6a4de5

So the request would be: `website/script.php?id=12&mail=mymail@mail.com&password=AERF124F&signature=0b9492395c9c1a73a6622cab5a6a4de5`

So in your php script you sould calculate the md5 hash of all parameters + the secret passphrase and see if those match.
**If they match, the request is valid, you can proceed, if they don't match someone is trying to hijack the database, ignore it!**

Comment: yeah i see,
so finally it should looks like :

          http://mywebsite/service/baseClassUpdate.php?id=XX&mail=XXXX    &password=MD5PASS

? or i can forget the modification by url ? imma looking for the proper and safe way

Comment: oh ok i see, only me on the app and the server know the secret password, and if i add the params, its like a checksun.
Nice tricks, thx !

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Make the password random and at least 5-6 characters. Remember to pass in the user password only MD5 or AES1 SHA encrypted and NOT in plain text!